# Call graph generation using Spark (Soot -Eclipse framework) - memory issues

Tags: java, eclipse, soot

I'm trying to generate Call graph using Spark (in Soot -Eclipse framework) for java code. I started with HelloWorld. Even for this small example it looks like the system memory isn't enough.

```
Soot has run out of the memory allocated to it by the Java VM.
To allocate more memory to Soot, use the -Xmx switch to Java.
For example (for 400MB): java -Xmx400m soot.Main .
```

My machine is Windows based 4GB  Core I-5. The eclipse process running is javaw.exe. Is this out-of-memory behavior expected even for Helloworld using soot? I'm new to running profiling for java and im not sure if the library classes are adding a huge overhead.

OR maybe the right question is - how do i use the -Xmx switch for running Soot with more memory in Eclipse on Windows -anyone done this?

The command in Eclipse is below. Im using some simplification options in Spark Analysis.

```
soot.Main     --w --d C:\Users\nbalaji\workspace\HelloWorld\sootOutput 
--process-path C:\Users\nbalaji\workspace/HelloWorld/src;    
--cp /C:/Users/nbalaji/workspace/HelloWorld/bin/, < bunch of Java/jre7 files >
```

**Edit**: This is resolved now.
From the Soot survival guide: When setting up a run
conﬁguration you should add the following parameters to the JVM -Xmx512m
-Xss256m to increase the VM memory.

Comment: On further research I found [**this**](http://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/index.php/daniel/236-increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse) very helpful and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soot using much memory is not a bug. Your Hello-World program transitively calls thousands of methods, all of which are analyzed.

As the exception message suggests, you should use:

```
java -Xmx400m soot.Main ...
```

This is a JVM option, not a Soot option.